# How to protect project on github

Tags: github, project

I want to protect my project on Github. I just want me and my co-worker can download the project. How can I do that?
Thanks.

Comment: A quick google search yielded instructions on making a repo private: https://help.github.com/articles/making-a-public-repository-private/
You'll have to set up a paid account with github I think.

Comment: The github website doesn't document this process at all?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called a '[private repository](https://help.github.com/articles/making-a-public-repository-private/)'.

Private repositories are not available for free accounts so you will have to get [an upgrade for you account](https://github.com/pricing).

Answer (score 1):

You need a premium account to make private repositories

https://github.com/pricing

Answer (score 1):

You can make the repository private. In order to do this you must be paying for github because it is not available on the free version. Bitbucket allows for unlimited private repositories and serves the same purpose.